# how can i put all the children of a movieClip into an Array?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages

I have an movieClip Container and I want to move all its children into an Array.
i think about the method I used to delete all children of a container by using while and removechild at 0, but I think it wont work in this situation. Anyone have a solution?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var parObj:DisplayObjectContainer = Container; /* Is that the name of your MC? */
var kids:Array = []
var kidCount:int = parObj.numChildren;
// please see note on push at bottom
for( var i:int = 0; i < kidCount; i++ ) kids.push( parObj.getChildAt( i ) );
```

TA-DA! kids is now an array of all children of parObj

as a function:

```
function getChildren( parObj:DisplayObjectContainer ):Array
{
    var kids:Array = []
    var kidCount:int = parObj.numChildren;
    for( var i:int = 0; i < kidCount; i++ ) 
        kids.push( parObj.getChildAt( i ) );
    return kids
}
```

Or, if you're courageous enough for vectors (the result of this function can only hold DisplayObjects and it is slightly faster than a normal array):

```
function getChildren( parObj:DisplayObjectContainer ):Vector.<DisplayObject>
{
    var Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
    var kidCount:int = parObj.numChildren;
    for( var i:int = 0; i < kidCount; i++ ) 
        kids.push( parObj.getChildAt( i ) );
    return kids
}
```

### EDIT

It was pointed out that this loop was not optimizing numChildren. I will agree (within reason -- chances are this will not be a bottleneck), so it is now an int. A good point to that SOer.

But, there have been two comments made vis-a-vis push vs. `kids[ kids.length ] = parObj.getChildAt( i );`

When it comes to assigning array indexes, my experience is that situations where `push` vs. `arr[ i ] = val` truly make that much of a difference, it is likely that something else is going on which should be optimized first -- are you really getting an array of the children of a MovieClip hundreds (thousands?) of times? Then maybe you don't really need an array of DisplayObject, maybe you need to remove the extra loop and handle all of this (more or less) inline. Do you really have a thousand length array? Then your bottleneck is probably going to be related to the fact that you're dealing with a large, unwieldy data structure and not the loop in itself.

I find `push` to be clear, explicit, and most important, obvious. `arr.push` takes no time to understand, it is a self-contained statement, whereas array index assignment requires me, at least, to actually look. Further, because `push` is a method call and `arr.length` is a property of a dynamic object, `push` also defends against the possibility of typos: `arr[ arr.lengt ]` causes no errors! It is valid code! `arr.pus(value)`, on the other hand, causes a `TypeError`. Don't know about the rest of the world, but I don't have time to deal with obscured typos.

Assigning array indexes directly, to me, is premature optimization. If you feel otherwise, that's fine (and by all means, vote me down, that is the point of the site -- hopefully we'll all agree on an acceptable practice), but `push` will be my standard.

Comment: @cwallenpoole kids[i] = getChildAt(i) is not that hard to write, it is not a rocketscience type of optimization. Does it make better job — yes, so just write it and go further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`numChildren`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#numChildren) and [`getChildAt()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt%28%29) to loop through your elements within a container. The following code assumes that you're running the code from within the container. If this isn't the case, just prefix those two properties with the name of your container:

```
var ar:Array = [];

var i:int = 0;
for(i; i<numChildren; i++)
{
    var mc:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);

    ar[ar.length] = mc;
}

trace(ar.length);
```

Comment: You should be using push and not `ar[ar.length]`. You'll have a casting error as `getChildAt(i)` returns a DisplayObject. uint is not well suited to iteration, not only is it slower, but it is "primarily useful for pixel color values (ARGB and RGBA) and other situations where the int data type does not work well."

Comment: Good info on the last point (I had always assumed uint was better suited because loops generally don't go below zero), but fyi array[array.length] is actually slightly faster than push(). Also good point on the typecasting issue; but it's only an issue if one of children isn't a MovieClip (which sadly I assumed everything would be).